# Spring dependency injection - best design pattern of configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Right now i have a inherited project that is using annotation based spring dependency injection. So all classes are simply marked with @Component (or specific stereoTypes like @service, @Repository,@RestController, etc).  This makes it a little hard to find where the dependency is located and i was thinking to change it so that each package has its own dependency configuration and then add each package to the @ComponentScan afterwards.

So for example if i had a package called com.mycoolpackage.login and mycoolpackage.networking
then i'd have a Spring configuration like this in first package:

```
 @Configuration

    public class LoginDIConfig {

        @Bean
        public LoginServiceImpl loginServiceImpl() {
            return new LoginServiceImpl();
        }

    }
```

and in the second package i'd have the following:

```
@Configuration

public class NetworkDIConfig {

    @Bean
    public NetworkServiceImpl networkServiceImpl() {
        return new NetworkServiceImpl();
    }

}
```

and my@ComponentScan would look like this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycoolpackage.login","com.mycoolpackage.network"})
```

So i have two questions about this approach.

1. How can i use a @Service annotation instead of bean here
2. Do you think this design is more easier as it tells you what your package dependencies are very easily instead of hunting them
   down.

Comment: I see 2 questions, not one.

Comment: One of those 2 questions asks for "best practice" and is therefore off topic as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure some been properties manually then you should go for above configuration else you should stick with exiting one.

```
This makes it a little hard to find where the dependency is located
```

@Autowire Or @Inject annotation will always lead you to dependency class.

Comment: it wont let me use stereotype annotations. It only allows Bean in @ configuration. it says when i try to use @ Service annotation for example that it cant be use on method.  I am assuming its  a class annotation so how do i use it in above example ?

Comment: You can't. As you already noticed, `@Service`, `@Component` etc. are annotations which should be used on classes, which should be scanned by Spring as components.